# Locrot with amature isn't moving mesh at all when playing in timeline

Tags: animation

I'm doing a school project with a greek solider and I'm getting the last part of creating my model done. My mesh is supposed to simply move his head side to side. When I move his head to one side I press `i>LocRot` record it to the timeline then move the cursor to frame 40 and repeat the process. But when I play the animation nothing happens at all.[image]

Comment: The stick bone type can make it hard to tell if the bone is rotating. Try switching to something like octahedral and see if the bone is rotating or not.

Comment: @Brenticus do I use LocRot on the model or the amature? (I'm kinda new to this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]As Brenticus said in his comment the stick bone type can make it hard to tell if the bone is rotating so I switched to octahedral and it works!